# "git push dokku" keeps asking for "dokku@..." password

Tags: git, ssh, git-push, dokku

On my remote server all I did is:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.26.6/bootstrap.sh;
sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.26.6 bash bootstrap.sh

dokku apps:create node-sample
```

Then on my local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/pedropaf/node-sample-dokku
cd .\node-sample-dokku\

git remote add dokku dokku@116.123.123.123:node-sample

ssh-keygen -f vincent

cat vincent.pub | ssh root@116.123.123.123 dokku ssh-keys:add git-deploy
```

(I can see the ssh key when I run ssh-keys:list in my remote server)

still locally:

```
ssh-add vincent
```

Then when I run:

```
git push dokku main
```

I receive:

```
dokku@116.123.123.123's password:
```

I don't understand why it doesn't establish the ssh connection and request the user password instead (user that doesn't exist)

Comment: git remote -v

dokku   dokku@116.123.123.123:node-sample-dokku (fetch)
dokku   dokku@116.123.123.123:node-sample-dokku (push)
origin  https://github.com/pedropaf/node-sample-dokku (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/pedropaf/node-sample-dokku (push)

Comment: my local machine = windows

Comment: What happens if you run `ssh dokku@116.123.123.123 echo test`? (add `-v` or more than one `-v` to the ssh invocation if that requires a password, to see why it requires a password.) If that *works*, the only reason `git`'s `ssh` invocation would require a password is if Git is running a different ssh program that stores its ssh keys in a different location. This can happen easily on Windows because Git comes with an ssh in case the Windows ssh is inadequate.

Comment: If the result of this testing shows that Git is running its own ssh instead of the system one. If the system one works (it should on modern Windows), tell Git to run the system one (configure `core.sshCommand` as needed).

Comment: Thanks @torek:

I got that:

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/id_xmss

Comment: Do any of those keys work? Are those the right keys? (I don't see `vincent.pub` in the list here.)

Comment: I haven't tried these ones. How can I add vincent.pub ?

Comment: See VonC's answer: the `ssh_config` file lists extra keys to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are following the article "[Hosting NodeJs Apps on Your Own Heroku, Using Dokku](https://www.pedroalonso.net/blog/hosting-nodejs-in-dokku)" from [Pedro Alonso](https://www.pedroalonso.net/)

The problem is: you are using a non-default naming convention for your SSH key (`vincent.pub` for you, `dokku_rsa.pub` in the article)

For a git push to work, you would need:

- an `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config` file set to reference your private key
- a remote URL using the `.ssh/config` Host entry

That is

```sh
# .ssh/config
Host dokku
  Hostname 116.123.123.123
  User dokku
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vincent
```

And:

```
cd /C/path/to/local/clone
git remote set-url dokku dokku:node-sample
```

Then a `git push` would use your private key.

---

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239657/discussion-between-vonc-and-vincent-roye) and the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140352/git-push-dokku-keeps-asking-for-dokku-password/70147374#comment124010217_70147374), Vincent has found "[SSH-Key authentication fails](https://superuser.com/a/1145465/141)" and did:

```sh
sudo chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/ -R
sudo chmod o-rwx /home/dokku/ -R
```

That was enough to make the `dokku` SSH URL work.

Comment: That,s right, I am following that tutorial. I think that I'm getting closer. I created the config file that you mentionned: 1) without moving the "vincent" file in the ssh folder and I received the following error: "no such identity: %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/vincent3: No such file or directory". 2) Then I placed the "vincent" file in the folder and I am getting the dokku@116... password prompt.

Comment: I supposed that it's trying to establish an ssh connection but something is still wrong. I can't figure out how to debug it.

Comment: I meant "%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/vincent" in my first comment

Comment: @VincentRoye Did you change the remote URL origin? And do you see your key used when testing a `ssh -Tv dokku`?

Comment: I changed the remote origin with : git remote set-url dokku dokku:node-sample

Comment: @VincentRoye OK, so you need to test if `ssh -Tv dokku` does use your private key. Once the ssh call is working, your `git push` will too.

Comment: I tried ssh -Tv dokku and I got:

debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/vincent  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

Comment: debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Vincent/.ssh/vincent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
dokku@116.123.123.123's password:

Comment: @VincentRoye That means the public key has not been properly added to `116.123.123.123:~dokku/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: it looks like that in the authorized_keys file:

command="FINGERPRINT=SHA256:f***U NAME=\"vincent\" `cat /home/dokku/.sshcommand` $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",no-agent-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa A****A vincent@MSI^M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239657/discussion-between-vonc-and-vincent-roye).

Comment: I did what @VonC suggested and also run:
sudo chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/ -R
sudo chmod o-rwx /home/dokku/ -R
in my remote server

Comment: @VincentRoye Good catch, well done! I have included your comment and relevant link in the answer for more visibility.